# Is there a simple DirectShow filter that can mix audio together of the exact same format?

Tags: delphi, filter, directshow, mixing, dspack

I have a DirectShow application written in Delphi 6 using the DSPACK component library.  I want to be able to mix together audio coming from the output pins from multiple Capture Filters that are set to the exact same media format.  Is there an open source or "sdk sample" filter that does this?

I know that intelligent mixing is a big deal and that I'd most likely have to buy a commercial library to do that.  But all I need is a DirectShow filter that can accept wave audio input from multiple output pins and does a straight addition of the samples received.  I know there are Tee Filter's for splitting a single stream into multiple streams (one-to-many), but I need something that does the opposite (many-to-one), preferably with format checking on each input connection attempt so that any attempt to attach an output pin with a different media format than the ones already added is thwarted with an error.   Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about anything available out of the box, however it would be definitely a third party component.

The complexity of creating this custom filter is not very high (it is not a rocket science in terms of creating such component yourself for specific need). You basically need to have all input audio converted to the same PCM format, match the timestamps, add the data and then deliver via output pin.

Comment: The mechanics of handling the data are indeed as you say easy, but I am finding that figuring out what of the usual Transform filter interface I can dispense with (return "not implemented", etc.), and what I have to support is requiring a good degree of study: (upstream/downstream notifications, format negotiation, seeking, etc.).  So far I've decided to dispense with seeking since I don't need it, I'll figure out the rest later.